# 2D string array(with local Turkish characters) sorting in java

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array, arrays

i have a 2D array of string it is like:

```
gsdfsdf | awfdsf 
asdasd  | sjd    
çsadsfd | kdjfkj 
bsdmfbs | skfjef 
ıfjdhsb | döjfn  
zewkjf  | skjfkj 
iadsa   | dfjdkj
```

i want to sort it according to first column as you see it has local(Turkish) characters, and after sorting it must be like:

```
asdasd  | sjd    
bsdmfbs | skfjef 
çsadsfd | kdjfkj 
gsdfsdf | awfdsf 
ıfjdhsb | döjfn  
iadsa   | dfjdkj 
zewkjf  | skjfkj
```

any idea, tutorial or advice?

Comment: output should be `i` before `i` I think

Comment: i know it does not matter really, in  official Turkish alphabet i comes before ı, but in general use ı comes before i

Comment: I added an answer wich is most a hint than an answer. Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparator should be improved for null checking,.. etc. but this should work!

```
final String alphabet = "0123456789AaBbCcÇçDdEeFfGgĞğHhIıİiJjKkLlMmNnOoÖöPpQqRrSsŞşTtUuÜüVvWwXxYyZz";
SortedMap<String,String> map = new TreeMap(new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int n = Math.min(o1.length(), o2.length());
            int i=0;
            while((i < n) && (o1.charAt(i) == o2.charAt(i))){
                i++;
            }
            if(i==n){
                return 0;
            }
            if(alphabet.indexOf(o1.charAt(i)) < alphabet.indexOf(o2.charAt(i))){
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Comparison only takes place on key set of TreeMap, so you can use `TreeMap<String, String[]>` definition and add your two column as a value of the map.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full working solution, but a hint.

Java provides a [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class for locale sensitive string comparison.

Sample (with guava):

### Foo

```
package com.stackoverflow.so13895464;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Foo {
    public static String sortAndOutput(final String in)
    {
        final List<String> split = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on('\n').split(in));
        Collections.sort(split, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2)
            {
               final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr_TR"));
               // XXX: toUpperCase to avoid a dotless i problem (was at the end)
               return collator.compare(o1.toUpperCase(), o2.toUpperCase()); 
            }
        });
        return Joiner.on('\n').join(split);
    }
}
```

### FooTest

```
package com.stackoverflow.so13895464;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void testSort()
    {
        final String in = "gsdfsdf | awfdsf\nasdasdsjd\nçsadsfd | kdjfkj\nbsdmfbs | skfjef\n" +  
            "ıfjdhsb | döjfn\nzewkjf  | skjfkj\niadsa   | dfjdkj";
        final String exp = "asdasd  | sjd\nbsdmfbs | skfjef\nçsadsfd | kdjfkj\ngsdfsdf | awfdsf\n" +
            "ıfjdhsb | döjfn\niadsa   | dfjdkj\nzewkjf  | skjfkj";
        assertEquals(exp, Foo.sortAndOutput(in));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i try this but "Locale.forLanguageTag("tr_TR")" is not supported now. I use "new Locale("tr", "TR")" and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a 2D array of string I'd use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). This will give you ability to sort on the key of the TreeMap. By default this is naturally ordered so it will be based alphabetically which is what you need although I'm not sure where alphabetically you want the Turkish characters.

```
TreeMap tm = new TreeMap(); 
// Put elements to the map 
tm.put("Zoe Doe", "First entry"); 
tm.put("Alex Smith", "Second entry"); 
tm.put("Gareth Baker", "Third entry");
// Get a set of the entries 
Set set = tm.entrySet(); 
// Get an iterator 
Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
// Display elements 
while(i.hasNext()) { 
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": "); 
System.out.println(me.getValue()); 
}
```

This should output the values of the TreeMap in alphabetical order:

- Alex Smith
- Gareth Baker
- Zoe Doe

If you need to change this then you can implement comparable and pass it in on the constructor of the TreeMap:

```
TreeMap tm = new TreeMap(new Comparator<Foo>()
             {
                 public int compare(Foo f1, Foo f2)
                 {
                     return f1.toString().compareTo(f2.toString());
                 }        
             });
```

You'll have to put the logic you want in the compare method above. As it seems you may need a different implementation than the standard alphabetical ordering.

Comment: it sorts but not for Turkish alphet and it is not case sensitive rows which begins with a turkish chracter are always at the and of the list