# List ParseData results to simpleListView on Android

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

I want to list my ArrayList items to the simple list view. I tried to convert ArrayList(iller) to StringArray(mListe) but I couldn't. It gives me always NullPointerException. What is my mistakes and how can I solve this problem Thank you for any help.

This is my List Fragment;

```
public class ListeFragment extends ListFragment {

public View mView;
public String[] mListe;
public ListView listView;
public ArrayList<String> iller = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_liste, container, false);

    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getOnlineDataFromParse();


}

private void setIlcelerArray(){

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), R.layout.ilce_view, mListe);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    listView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    googleAnalyticsSendScreen();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ListVets.class);

            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            intent.putExtra("ilce", mListe[position]);
            startActivity(intent);


            //GOOGLE ANALYTICS EVENT SENDER
            String secilenilce = "Seçilen ilçe " + mListe[position];

            Tracker t = ((GlobalState) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
                    GlobalState.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

            t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory("İlçeler Listesi")
                    .setAction("Seçilen ilçe")
                    .setLabel(secilenilce)
                    .build());
        }
    });
}

private void getOnlineDataFromParse(){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Veterinerler");
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> vetList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                for(int i=0; i< vetList.size(); i++){

                    iller.add(vetList.get(i).getString("il"));

                }

                mListe = iller.toArray(new String[iller.size()]);

                setIlcelerArray();

            } else {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.parse_online_query_error_title));
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.parse_online_query_error_message));
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }

        }

    });

}
```

There is the logCat ;

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.esmobileinc.vetmapp.u.k(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.C(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.d(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.e(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.b(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.aa.b(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.c(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you !

Comment: https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
```

^ParseQueryAdapter is what we use to load ParseObject(s) into a ListView. After declaring a ParseQueryAdapter you will want to make a ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory and apply it to your adapter.

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory;
factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("ParseObject");
                return query;
            }
        };
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory) {
    @Override
    public View getItemView(final ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_list_view, null);
        }
        return v;
    }
};
mainAdapter.setPaginationEnabled(true);
mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");
mainAdapter.setImageKey("Image");
mainAdapter.loadObjects();
```

If you want to do something more like this you may get some success. If you look at the getItemView() method you can see where I reference the xml listview file.

Comment: First of all. Thank you. Your codes are working like a charm. But there are 2  problem here. 1st = I don't want to fetch same strings from my ParseCore. How can I handle this ?
2nd problem is = Parse orderByDescending method is not working right with Turkish language so how can I fix it with using Comparator or another way ? 

you are lifesaver. Thank you again.

Comment: try this for the second part "query.orderByDescending("createdAt");" I will look into the first question

Comment: I want to orderByDescending method for my strings. This approach is very easy and super fast but I think this approach is not good for me ?

Comment: Oh so you want the posts to be alphabetically ordered by the string values themselves?

Comment: Yes and its not working with Turkish Language I have to use Comparator I can't add the fetched data to my array. Did you find anything about same values ? I have to fetch unique values only.

Comment: Well Im wondering if there is possibility to compare by ACII value but that seems like an absurd path to have to take, language conversion should be more simple but I have yet to run into this problem. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895464/2d-string-arraywith-local-turkish-characters-sorting-in-java