# Custom ListView Android, no results displayed in ListView

Tags: android, parse-platform

Updated code; however I am still getting no results when running the app.

I am using ParseQueryAdapter; I am querying the user, so am using ParseUser; it seems the first part is a query for all users of type midwife, then getting specific types of data I want, setting them to the TextViews

```
public class CustomMidwifeAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> {


    public CustomMidwifeAdapter(Context context) {
        // Use the QueryFactory to construct a PQA that will only show
        // Todos marked as high-pri
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>() {
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("userType");
                query.whereEqualTo("userType", "midwife");
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null ) {

                            //query was successful


                        }

                    else {
                            //Something went wrong
                        }

                    }


                });



                return query;
            }
        });
    }



    public View getItemView(ParseUser object, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_midwife_result_list, null);

        }

        super.getItemView(object, view, parent);


        // Add the practicename view
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicename);
        titleTextView.setText(object.getString("practicename"));

        // Add education view
        TextView EducationView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.education);
        EducationView.setText(object.getString("education"));

        // Add yearsexperience view
        TextView ExperienceView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yearsinpractice);
        ExperienceView.setText(object.getString("yearsinpractice"));

        //Add practice philosophy view
        TextView PracticePhilosophyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicephilosophy);
        PracticePhilosophyView.setText(object.getString("practicephilosophy"));


        return view;
    }

}
```

Here is the activity

```
public class MidwifeResultList extends Activity {


    private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;

    private CustomMidwifeAdapter midwifeListAdapter;

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list)

        //initialize main ParseQueryAdapter
        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "userType");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("practicename");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("education");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("yearsinpractice");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("practicephilosophy");


        // Initialize the subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
        midwifeListAdapter = new CustomMidwifeAdapter(this);

        // Initialize ListView and set initial view to mainAdapter
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMidwives);
        listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        mainAdapter.loadObjects();

    }
```

I've checked my listview, and the id's seem to be correct.  This is based on this example: https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter

Comment: Adapter serves as widget source for ListView, so double check what values you return from `getCount()` and `isEmpty()` methods. Another feature is correctly handling DataSetObserver object passed to you by ListView, so you could notify it when data in adapter was updated.

Comment: Please post the complete code of your activity and of your adapter. How on Earth do you expect people to help otherwise?! Anyway, are you calling `findInBackground` from an `AsyncTask`? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @LigamentThrasher I added in the code..yeah, that findInBackground is in the Parse Docs, for setting up a ParseQuery...

Comment: Debug your code and check if `midwifelist` have some data in `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: Okay so there is much wrong with this code but that's okay it can be fixed. First and foremost your data model needs to correspond with how parse Objects are used for queries, you don't even extend ParseObject so I would start there. As for the listview and the adapter, check out this post that I posted a while back. It has some relative implementation as to what you are trying to do and I think it will help a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101944/list-parsedata-results-to-simplelistview-on-android/29102837#29102837

Comment: @aquaballin_dc I'm noticing the example linked to does not have a data model...the github code has an adapter, main class...so is the data model not needed?

Comment: No your object won't save to parse if it dosent extend parseobject